# c# xml serialization how to add "encoding"

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to serialize an xml in C# project and I am almost done. I am trying to add a namespace to `<xml>` node at top. this is how I add a namespace to my first node below

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "otv_ek44_bildirimleri.xsd");
```

how do you add namespace to the `<xml>` node?

I want it to be like below. I want to add encoding title to XML node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vimveritransferi xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="otv_ek44_bildirimleri.xsd">
```

Comment: You first talk about wanting to add a namespace, then about an encoding attribute, and the desired result does not define the `xsi` prefix.

Comment: Have you found the answer? I have the same problem

Comment: Declaration for xml document is explained there and it solved my problem. xmlDocument https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createxmldeclaration.aspx